# Using PHP to automate @font-face path

Tags: php, directory, font-face

I am very new to Php and was wondering if i could automate this process. Is there a way to make this a little more compact using php? So that i can easely update custom fonts by just putting it in a directory (called fonts). All idea's are welcome! If you know a better solution or simply advise that i should not do this that is also fine.

```
/* ======================================================
    ► FONT-LIBRARY
   ====================================================== */

/*Brandon Grotesque*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_thin';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin/brandon_thin.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin/brandon_thin.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin/brandon_thin.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin/brandon_thin.svg#brandon_grotesquethin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_thin_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin_it/brandon_thin_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin_it/brandon_thin_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin_it/brandon_thin_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_thin_it/brandon_thin_it.svg#brandon_grotesquethin_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_light';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light/brandon_light.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light/brandon_light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light/brandon_light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light/brandon_light.svg#brandon_grotesquelight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_light_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light_it/brandon_light_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light_it/brandon_light_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light_it/brandon_light_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_light_it/brandon_light_it.svg#brandon_grotesquelight_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_reg';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg/brandon_reg.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg/brandon_reg.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg/brandon_reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg/brandon_reg.svg#brandon_grotesque_regularRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_reg_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg_it/brandon_reg_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg_it/brandon_reg_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg_it/brandon_reg_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg_it/brandon_reg_it.svg#brandon_grotesqueRgIt') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_med';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med/brandon_med.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med/brandon_med.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med/brandon_med.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med/brandon_med.svg#brandon_grotesquemedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_med_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med_it/brandon_med_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med_it/brandon_med_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med_it/brandon_med_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_med_it/brandon_med_it.svg#brandon_grotesqueMdIt') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_bld';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld/brandon_bld.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld/brandon_bld.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld/brandon_bld.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld/brandon_bld.svg#brandon_grotesquebold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_bld_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld_it/brandon_bld_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld_it/brandon_bld_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld_it/brandon_bld_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_bld_it/brandon_bld_it.svg#brandon_grotesquebold_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_blk';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk/brandon_blk.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk/brandon_blk.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk/brandon_blk.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk/brandon_blk.svg#brandon_grotesqueblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandon_blk_it';
    src: url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk_it/brandon_blk_it.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk_it/brandon_blk_it.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk_it/brandon_blk_it.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_blk_it/brandon_blk_it.svg#brandon_grotesqueblack_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

(Sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SASS Mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) to do something more readable.

Here is a mixin I often use :

```
@mixin font-face($font-name, $file-name, $weight: normal, $style: normal) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: quote($font-name);
    src: url($file-name + '.otf') format('opentype');
    src: url($file-name + '.eot');
    src: url($file-name + '.eot?#iefix')  format('embedded-opentype'),
    url($file-name + '.woff') format('woff'),
    url($file-name + '.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url($file-name + '.svg##{$font-name}')  format('svg');
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
  }
}
```

And after I can do that for example :

```
// BRANDON GROTESQUE
// ================================

$directory-font-brandonGrotesque: './Brandon-Grotesque';

@include font-face('Brandon Grotesque', $directory-font-brandonGrotesque + '/blabla', 300, 'italic');
@include font-face('Brandon Grotesque', $directory-font-brandonGrotesque + '/blabla', 300);
@include font-face('Brandon Grotesque', $directory-font-brandonGrotesque + '/blabla', 400);
@include font-face('Brandon Grotesque', $directory-font-brandonGrotesque + '/blabla', 500);
@include font-face('Brandon Grotesque', $directory-font-brandonGrotesque + '/blabla', 700);
```

If you really need to do it automatically, I think [GULP](https://gulpjs.com/) or any other task manager can help you to achieve it.